# Making field/property readable but not writable from outside the class

Tags: c#, class

I have a class `Person` which I need to have a property/field `Age`.

I want Age to be readable anywhere, but only `Grow()` should be able to change it's value.

If I make `Age` public, then it can be modified from outside, so it won't work for me.

Making it private prevents being read from outside.

I also tried making it an autoproperty with only a get method, but then the variable becomes readonly and can only be set in the construtor.

Of course I can make Age `private` and create a function `int GetAge()` which returns `Age`.

The problem here is that if my class has a lot of such fields I have to create a get function for each of them.

Is making the function `int GetAge()` the only way of solving this, or there's somethig else that allows to easily have properties or fields readable but not writable from outside the class?

```
class Person
{
  private int _age;

  Person(int age)
  {
    _age = age;
  }

  void Grow() 
  {
    _age++;
  }
  
  int GetAge() 
  {
    return (_age);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties can have individual access descriptors for read and write.  So, your class can be:

```
public class Person
{
  public int Age {get; private set; }

  public Person(int age)
  {
    Age = age;
  }

  public void Grow() 
  {
    Age++;
  }
}
```

If you only set `Age` in the constructor, and did not change it in any of the methods, you could have declared it as `public int Age {get;}`

Comment: Age is also set in the function `Grow()` so it cannot be read-only. I'll try this suggestion thanks.

Comment: ... or use a backing field.